# form.as_p displays only one first input in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to use my form in django template but only one input displaying on the page

**Template**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Screenshot from page
[image: screenshot]

**Form**

```
class JournalRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = JournalRecord
        fields = ('shutdown_datetime', 'approximate_turn_on_datetime', 'shutdown_type', 'shutdown_reason', 'additional_information')
```

**Model**

```
class JournalRecord(models.Model):
    record_creation_datetime = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Дата і час запису', auto_now_add=True, null=False, blank=False)
    record_close_datetime = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Дата і час відміни заяви', default=None, null=True, blank=True)
     ......
    additional_information = models.TextField(verbose_name='Додаткова інформація', null=True, blank=True)
```

**View**

```
class JournalRecordCreateView(CreateView, LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin):
    permission_required = ('dispatcher.add_journalrecord')
    model = JournalRecord
    form_class = JournalRecordForm
    fields = '__all__'
```

I have no idea what is wrong. I tried:

- manually pass `JournalRecordForm()` to template context
- change class based `CreateView` to `View`.

Answer (score 0):

Always put your parent main class at end of multi-inheritance.

model and fields are not necessary if you set form_class. And you do not have provided template_name, so your template is not used.

```py
class JournalRecordCreateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = ('dispatcher.add_journalrecord')
    form_class = JournalRecordForm
    template_name = "...PATH_TO_TEMPLATe.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, when I copied path to create new I forgot to change view

```
    path('journal/close/', views.JournalRecordCloseView.as_view(), name='journal_record_close'),
    path('journal/create/', views.JournalRecordCloseView.as_view(), name='journal_record_create'),
```